# How do I get units (NOT label) to be displayed on the X axis of a barplot?

Tags: r, bar-chart, units-of-measurement

I'm trying to create a data visualisation to show the number of schools broken down by the number of classes. I created a tibble that does this (I've pasted below) Where there are two columns, 'c(grade5$schlcode)' which shows a list of the unique school codes and 'n' which is the number of classes within each school code.

```
n_classes <- count(grade5, c(grade5$schlcode))
> 
> n_classes
# A tibble: 1,002 x 2
   `c(grade5$schlcode)`     n
                  <dbl> <int>
 1                11005     2
 2                11006     2
 3                11009     1
 4                11010     2
 5                11013     3
 6                11015     3
 7                11017     2
 8                11020     3
 9                11021     2
10                11027     3
# … with 992 more rows
```

I then tallied the number of schools in order to create a `tibble` to make this `barplot`.

```
> x <- count(n_classes, c(n_classes$n))
> x
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  `c(n_classes$n)`     n
             <int> <int>
1                1   296
2                2   456
3                3   199
4                4    42
5                5     8
6                6     1
```

But when I make the plot it shows correctly the frequency of schools that have 1 class and 2 classes and 3 classes and so on, but i has not displayed the units of X axis (so each bar should be labelled 1, 2, 3, 4 (classes). But there's no units only the xlab!

```
> barplot(x$n, x$`c(n_classes$n)`,
+         xlab = "Number of Classes in a School",
+         ylab = "Frequency of Schools",
+         main = "Number of Classes Schools Have",
+         col = "grey",
+         border = "orange")
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: The usual convention is to put the units in the `xlab` or `ylab`, e.g. "Number of Classes in a School (count)".  If you want to put "(count)" somewhere else, you'll probably need to use `mtext()` to place it there explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You have a really weird column name for the count number, and it is causing a lot of problems:

```
x = data.frame("`c(n_classes$n)`" = 1:6,
n=c(296,456,199,42,8,1),check.names=FALSE)
```

If we do,

```
x$`c(n_classes$n)`
NULL
```

This is because it interprets ` as a string. You can try:

```
barplot(x$n,x$"`c(n_classes$n)`",
         xlab = "Number of Classes in a School",
         ylab = "Frequency of Schools",
         main = "Number of Classes Schools Have",
         col = "grey",
         border = "orange")
```

[image]

All these can be avoided by just calling table twice on the vector:

```
set.seed(100)
grade5 = data.frame(schlcode=sample(1:20,100,replace=TRUE))
barplot(table(table(grade5$schlcode)))
```

[image]